# Selecting a yet unknown DB table with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops

My problem is i dont know what db table i need to connect to until i have performed the first query. the image_library and text_library tables both have different fields.

I currently have it working with if else statements but feel there a better way to do this.

I want to be able to add library's in the future, so this method doesn't seem to be modularized enough.

```
$obj_results = mysql_query("SELECT library_sets.library_table FROM objects
LEFT JOIN library_sets ON library_sets.id=objects.library_set_id
WHERE objects.status_id='1' AND objects.block_id='$block_id' ORDER BY position ASC",$con_web) or die (mysql_error());
while($obj_rows=mysql_fetch_array($obj_results))
{
  $object_library_table=$obj_rows["library_table"];

  if($object_library_table=="image_library")
  {
    connect to db table with specific select statement
  }
    else if($object_library_table=="text_library")
  {
    connect to db table with specific select statement
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have both select statement different parameters?

Comment: Are there only ever two possibilities for which table you would use? If that's the case, then a simple if/else is exactly what you want. That's exactly what the control flow statement was designed for.

Comment: both select statements have different parameters.

Comment: What you have is fine, especially since you mentioned the queries against each table will be different.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just had the feeling i was missing something obvious.

Comment: If you get to a point where you have 20 tables, the `if...else` gets ugly, and then you can create a map of `TABLE_NAME => SQL_TO_RUN` and use it when you know which table is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the MySQL control structures to do that in just one query:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html